# click event wont let scroll event fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, onclick

I am making a parallax scroller with clickout events on child elements.

```
<div class="parralaxParallaxScroller---1" data-ltr="true" data-column="0" style="left: 172px; width: 768px; height: 1153px; position: absolute; top: 3374px; z-index: 0;"><img onclick="location.href='http://admaxim.com' " src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.admaxim/r6woe2.jpeg" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0"></div>
```

the issue i am facing is that when image is scrolled in the view on mobile devices. scroll stops working. i think its because of that onclick event. as on images without url scroll works fine.
any ideas how to avoid it?

Comment: try wrapping the image tag with an <a> tag and add the onClick event to the <a> tag. eg: <a><img></a>.

Comment: thanks @AlexisToby Thats worked.

Comment: i dont know why but it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work. Thank you.

```
<div class="parralaxParallaxScroller---1" data-ltr="true" data-column="0" style="left: 172px; width: 768px; height: 1153px; position: absolute; top: 3374px; z-index: 0;">
        <a onclick="location.href='http://admaxim.com'">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.admaxim/r6woe2.jpeg" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0">
        </a>
    </div>
```